# How do I check my ios app version history detail on itunesconnect

Tags: ios, state, app-store-connect

Now My app was update to version 1.4, So can't find my app's version 1.0 states on itunesconnect.
Now I really need my version 1.0's detail such as app create date or sth....
Does any one can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any app's version history is now available in the iTunes application on the app's page, under Version History.

Comment: It seem to be truncating history to only show 25 recent updates.

Answer (score 6):

In case anybody wonders how services like sensortower get this data:

Unfortunately there is no API for this. The iTunes App Page seems to get this info out of the `versionHistory` array deep inside `its.serverData`.

For the response to include this, the request needs these HTTP headers:

```
X-Apple-Store-Front : 143445-2,32
apple-originating-system : MZStore
```

Here link with sample request and response: https://gist.github.com/catlan/30b2e87dedb00733e4e223e60fd08c63

Notes about `X-Apple-Store-Front`:

```
iTunes: 143445-2,32
Mac App Store: 143445-2,13
Volume Purchase Programme for Business: 143445-2,14
Volume Purchase Programme for Education: 143445-2,11
JSON: 143445-2,20
```

This should also answer the (closed?) questions: [App Store API for release notes / updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838765/app-store-api-for-release-notes-updates/28849246#28849246) and [How to access complete version history of iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141573/how-to-access-complete-version-history-of-ios-app)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a service like Sensortower.
It regularly lists charecteristics of every app, so you can take those infos from there. 
This might be especially interesting, if you're looking for infos of a third party app, where you don't have the possibility, to log-in to the apple dev center or the like for detailed infos about *your* app.

E.g. details for Evernote: https://sensortower.com/ios/de/evernote/app/evernote/281796108

Comment: Well, I really don't think it's worth a downvote... Anyway, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can via a Chinese site [xinyou.com](http://xinyou.com).

Search by app name in the top search box, then on the app page, scroll down on the right, you'll see the update history listed by dates.
Click on the version number (any of them) to see the history notes.

That said, I am not sure evry app is there and am still looking for an English site equivalent, and some of the version updates show up in Chinese (these may be actual Chinese updates as I only see them on the really popular international apps (i.e. [Evernote](http://apps.xinyou.com/ios/subject/evernote/version)).

Hope this helps and hope someone has a better localsite option.

Comment: Unfortunately this service seems to be abolished.