# App Store API for release notes / updates

Tags: ios, api, app-store

Is there any way to retrieve the following information from the Apple (iOS) App Store:

a) the time and date an app from the app store has been updated 
b) retrieve release notes from the latest update

Is there an API for this? RSS? Or even an existing service that already provides this?

I would like to keep track of new updates of interesting apps, but don't want them always on my iPhone or check with iTunes on Mac.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can retrieve it with this api. It will return you data in json format.

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id="Your app's lookup id"

To find lookup id do this.

Suppose this is your app url

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/temple-run/id420009108?mt=8

then lookup id is "420009108" the text after the id.

Comment: there is no update date in that data

Comment: I can confirm that if you use the `bundleId` argument you will get a JSON response that includes a `releaseNotes` field. ie `http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.mycompany.myapp&country=US`

Comment: now there does have a field called `currentVersionReleaseDate` containing last release date

Answer (score 1):

@opafritz good news! I've added AppStore support into my pet-project: http://allmychanges.com/p/web/allmychanges/#0.19.0

This means that now you can track any app's release notes not having to install it on device!